# Why after cloning a single branch in git, does the directory not match?

Tags: git

I have been banging my head on this for an hour now.  I did a simple checkout: `git clone https://github.com/[repo name] -b [branch name] T`

Then when I look in T, I don't see the right branch!  I see the head or something like that.  When I go into T, I do `git log`, and I see the checkins I expect.  When I `git diff` the head with an old revision, I see the changes I expect.  I verified `git remote show origin` — everything looks good.

Why do the files in T not correspond to the appropriate branch?

---

```
~/src: git clone https://github.com/nouiz/Theano.git T
Cloning into 'T'...
remote: Counting objects: 141244, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Total 141244 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 141196
Receiving objects: 100% (141244/141244), 54.72 MiB | 1.91 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (112338/112338), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
~/src: cd T
~/src/T: git checkout NeilGirdhar-master
Branch NeilGirdhar-master set up to track remote branch NeilGirdhar-master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'NeilGirdhar-master'
```

Now, examining `theano/tensor/subtensor.py` does not match the [latest commit](https://github.com/nouiz/Theano/commit/b8c6186f8a164bee377fc4efbe589bf27773201a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repeated your example (cloning `https://github.com/nouiz/Theano.git`) and looked at your link to [commit b8c6186f8a164bee377fc4efbe589bf27773201a](https://github.com/nouiz/Theano/commit/b8c6186f8a164bee377fc4efbe589bf27773201a).  The diff (against the parent of that commit) shows changes to:

```
theano/tensor/tests/test_subtensor.py
```

but, I will note, not to:

```
theano/tensor/subtensor.py
```

Checking out that same branch by name gets me that same commit, and the `tests/test_subtensor.py` file has the contents implied by the diff on the github web page.

Is this just a case of cut-and-paste-o wrong file name?

Comment: Yes!  Oops!  You got it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation's confusing here. I think `git clone https://... -b [branch name]` will put you in a detached head state.

You typically don't clone a single branch. I think you'd achieve the results you expect like this:

```
git clone https://...
git checkout branchname
```

Read more about the clone options available [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still not working for me.  You're right that this checks out the right branch, but even though I `git log` and it shows a bunch of commits, those commits do not appear to be applied.  Is there a way I can make sure that I've applied all of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to restrict your clone to one branch:

```
--[no-]single-branch
           Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or the primary branch
           remote's HEAD points at. When creating a shallow clone with the --depth option, this is the default, unless --no-single-branch is
           given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches. Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the
           remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning. If the HEAD at the remote did not point at any
           branch when --single-branch clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is created.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried --single-brach, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry, Weird, cause the combo of --single-branch and --branch limited my clone to just that one branch specified as the active branch in the cloned repo and with history limited to that one branch.

Comment: You're right, this works, but for some reason even though the history is right in `git log`, it doesn't seem to be applied to the files in the folder.

Comment: I looked at my folders and they look correct per that branch. Are you really sure that you havent merged things so that your folder's files on that branch really aren't what they are in the other branch?